# Cannot access REST api on karaf

Tags: java, rest, osgi, apache-karaf

I am using Apache Karaf 4.0.1 with Java 1.8.  The java OSGi project already consumes SOAP messages, but I am trying to add a REST api.

I have added a module with a REST endpoint, and this compiles successfully using Maven.  However, if I try access the endpoint, I get an error.

REST Endpoint:

**HelloResource.java**

```
@Path("/")
public interface HelloResource {

    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @GET
    String hello();
}
```

**HelloResourceImpl.java**

```
public class HelloResourceImpl implements HelloResource {

    public String hello() {
        return "hello!";
    }
}
```

When I try access the REST endpoint:

**cmd line:**

> $ curl http://localhost:5005/hello
> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

**Karaf log:**

> Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >GET /hello
> HTT< - expected >JDWP-Handshake<

[image]

Project REST module:

[image]

Comment: 5005 is jdwp port (debugger attach protocol). When you start Karaf with pax-web features installed (like pax-http-jetty), it should listen on 8181 port (http).

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching to the debugging port 5005, not the Karaf application port which is 8181 by default. Try:

`curl http://localhost:8181/hello`